# HTML: при нажатии на переключатель radio - отобразить числовое поле ввода в той же линии

Tags: html, вёрстка, bootstrap4

При нажатии на переключатель типа `radio` "Указать размер" поле ввода отображается под переключателем (в колонке),а необходимо в отобразить в одной линии с переключателем. подскажите, пожалуйста, вариант решения

```css
#own:not(:checked) ~ #own-size { display: none }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<h3>Размер</h3>

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-start">

  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="answer" checked="checked" value="no" / id="man"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="man"> <h5>Стандартный мужской</h5> </label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="answer" value="yes" id="woman" /><label class="custom-control-label" for="woman"> <h5>Стандартный женский</h5> </label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio text-left mb-4" id="own-input">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="answer" value="other" id="own" /> <label class="custom-control-label" for="own"> <h5> Указать размер</h5> </label>

    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="own-size">
      <label class="sr-only" for="product-own-size-input">Size</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="product-own-size-input" placeholder="размер">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">см</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#own:not(:checked) ~ #own-size { display: none }
#own-input {display: flex}
#own-input label {flex-basis: 100%; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<h3>Размер</h3>

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-start">

  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="answer" checked="checked" value="no" / id="man"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="man"> <h5>Стандартный мужской</h5> </label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="answer" value="yes" id="woman" /><label class="custom-control-label" for="woman"> <h5>Стандартный женский</h5> </label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio text-left mb-4" id="own-input">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="answer" value="other" id="own" /> <label class="custom-control-label" for="own"> <h5> Указать размер</h5> </label>

    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="own-size">
      <label class="sr-only" for="product-own-size-input">Size</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="product-own-size-input" placeholder="размер">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">см</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
========================================================================
```

Как пример с флексом.
Думаю доработать не составит труда